# Postgresql и извращенное преобразование типов

Tags: postgresql, sql

Приветствую!
надеюсь не для кого не секрет что постгрес нативно умеет делать явные преобразования типов
  table.value::text или case(table.value as text)

но у меня появилая воспаленная идея, а реально ли делать такие преобразования типов беря значение после :: из поля какой-нито таблицы т.е как-то так:
table.value::(other_table.cell)  или cast(table.value as other_table.cell)
где в other_table.cell хранится строковое представление этого типа (text, text[], int, bool /etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что только в рамках динамического SQL.